# EditText hides error message when "digits" are set and forbidden character entered

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have EditText with `digits`

```
<EditText
        ...
        android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFabcdef"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions" />
```

And I check for input error in `TextWatcher`

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged");
        try {
            int color = Color.parseColor(s.toString());
        } catch (Exception e){
            editText.setError("Wrong color");
        }
    }
});
```

But when I enter any forbidden character (for example, `L`) the error message is reset, because input was changed, but none of `TextWatcher` methods are called, probably due to the `digits`.

I can somehow fix it without deleting `digits` and without manually handling forbidden characters in `TextWatcher`? Maybe there is a method that is guaranteed to be called on every input action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that wrong key press events come in `InputFilter`. But it overrides `maxLength` from xml (you can endlessly enter characters defined in `digits`), so it will have to be created manually in code.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter(){
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        // Check here for input error
        return source;
    }
};
InputFilter.LengthFilter lengthFilter = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(7);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{hexFilter, lengthFilter});
```